# ClassCastException when converting List<Map<String,Double>> to TreeSet<Map<String,Double>>

Tags: java

I cannot seem to figure out why I get this ClassCastException with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        

    Map<String,Double>          test0 = new TreeMap<String,Double>();
    test0.put("test", 1.);
    List<Map<String,Double>>    test1 = Arrays.asList(  test0 );

    Set<Map<String,Double>      test2 = new TreeSet<Map<String,Double>>( test1 )
}
```

So instead I try iterating through test1 and individually placing the maps into test2 as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        

    Map<String,Double>          test0 = new TreeMap<String,Double>();
    test0.put("test", 1.);
    List<Map<String,Double>>    test1 = Arrays.asList(  test0 );
    Set<Map<String,Double>>     test2 = new TreeSet<Map<String,Double>>();  

    for (Map<String,Double> mp : test1)
        test2.add(mp);
}
```

Both give the same exception involving Comparable:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1188)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
at Delete.main(Delete.java:20)
```

Any insight into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `TreeSet`? And if you've to use it, you've to provide a way to compare `Map`.

Comment: In my project, I use TreeSet to maintain a sorted order of non-duplicates. Should I use something different?

Comment: So, on what basis do you want the maps inside the `TreeSet` to be sorted?

Comment: The title is misleading

Comment: I changed the title to TreeSet from Set.

Comment: I thought the default sorting would be alphabetical on the strings in the keyset....no wait, I was thinking of the sorting of the maps, not the TreeSet. Yes, I have not considered the sorting of the maps inside the TreeSet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TreeSet` expects you to either pass in a `Comparator` for its element type, or for its elements to implement `Comparable`.  `Map` does not implement `Comparable`, and you haven't provided a `Comparator`.

It'd work out-of-the-box if you used a `HashSet`, though, since `Map` has a specified `hashCode()` implementation.